# Shopify How to output a product that doesn't have a collection

Tags: shopify

I am trying to output all the products in a menu up to a certain number than output the collection types when that number is reached. So far that works fine, however I don't know how to output a product if the user does not put the product in a collection, I would like the products not entered into a collection to be in a template that I can link to in the menu that outputs the products not in a collection.

Here is my code so far.

```
{% for collection in collections %}

      {% if shop.products_count <= 5 %}



      {% for product in collections.[collection.title].products %}
            {% capture productLink %}{{ product.url }}{% endcapture %}
            <a href="{{ productLink }}">{{product.title}}</a>

        {% endfor %}


      {% elsif shop.products_count > 5 %}

      {% capture collectionLink %}{{ collection.url }}{% endcapture %}


            <a href="{{ collectionLink }}">{{collection.title}}</a>

      {% else %}

            You have no Products

      {% endif %}


      {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably start by [making a collection that contains all products in your shop](http://docs.shopify.com/support/your-store/collections/taking-control-of-your-catalog-page) (a smart collection where Product price > 0).

Then on the page where you want to display the products that are not in any collection (except the one we just created), try something like this:

```
{% for product in collections.all.products %}
  {% if product.collections.size <= 1 %}
    This product is not in any collections other than collections.all
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```